# Celery inspect queries hang forever

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have a dockerized celery implementation with redis as broker. Currently I only run one worker instance for celery. To monitor celery, I also added flower docker service but I am unable to monitor as the request times out. Upon looking into things I found that my `celery inspect` queries are simply non responding. They hang forever. Now, I think there is an underlying issue with my celery-redis setup. I am unable to inspect anything, when I try to add a task for background processing they are getting stuck upon the calling statement itself. Its all behaving weird.

```
Versions:

celery 4.0.2
redis 5.0.0
```

Currently, I am unable to debug in any capacity. Any help is gladly appreciated.